# How to get Selenium to extract the link for each tweet via clicking "Copy link" on Twitter?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, twitter

I'm trying to extract the links to each specific tweet on Twitter using Selenium (with Python).  E.g., let's say I'm looking at https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3A%40POTUS&src=typed_query&f=live

Each tweet has this arrow button on the bottom-right

[image: Arrow]

that upon clicking, it reveals 3 more options, the first one being the "Copy link" option that saves the direct link of the tweet onto the clipboard.

[image]

How do I instruct Selenium to click that arrow + copy the link, and then save the URL for all the tweets on the page?

At the moment my code looks something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3A%40POTUS&src=typed_query&f=live")

links = []
articles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//article[@data-testid = "tweet"]')
for article in articles:
    link = article.find_element(By.XPATH, './/svg').click()   # cant figure it out
    links.append(link)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to click on icon to get tweet link.

Twit itself contains that link inside one of a elements.

Locator for that element is css selector `[data-testid=User-Name] a[role=link][href*=status]`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3A%40POTUS&src=typed_query&f=live")
# login there

links = []
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
hrefs = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid=User-Name] a[role=link][href*=status]')))
for href in hrefs:
    link = href.get_attribute('href')
    links.append(link)
    print(link)
```